# My app stops when a variable has null value. why?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@PostMapping("/order")
public Bill addOrder(@RequestBody Bill theBill) {
    
    theBill.setDate(timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        
    billService.save(theBill);
    
    List<BillDetails> billDetails1 = theBill.getBillDetails();
    
    for(BillDetails billDetails2:billDetails1)
    {
        Product product = billDetails2.getProduct();
        Location location = billDetails2.getLocation();
        Quality quality = billDetails2.getQuality();
        
        double quantity1 = billDetails2.getQuantity();
        
        LocationDetails locationDetails1 = locationDetailsService.findById(new LocationDetailsId(product,quality,location));
        
        if(locationDetails1 == null){
            
            LocationDetails locationDetails2 = new LocationDetails();
            
            LocationDetailsId locationDetailsId = new LocationDetailsId();
            
            locationDetailsId.setProduct(product);
            locationDetailsId.setLocation(location);
            locationDetailsId.setQuality(quality);
            
            locationDetails2.setQuantity(quantity1);
            
            locationDetails2.setLocationDetailsId(locationDetailsId);
            
            locationDetailsService.save(locationDetails2);
            
        }
        else {
        
            double quantity2 = locationDetails1.getQuantity();
            
            double quantity3 = quantity2 + quantity1;
            
            LocationDetails locationDetails3 = new LocationDetails();
            
            locationDetails3.setLocationDetailsId(locationDetails1.getLocationDetailsId());
            locationDetails3.setQuantity(quantity3);
            
            locationDetailsService.save(locationDetails3);
        }
        
    }
    
    return theBill;
}
```

Hi I'm new to springboot, here my app runs fine when I have values for locationDetails1 . but it stops running when locationDetails1 returns null value . The Error I'm getting is (did not found). I want to handle that in if clause which I did .But still I receive the error. how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ! operator like this...

if(!locationDetails1) ....

Comment: the problem is if the value of locationDetails1 is null the next line is not even executed

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting locationDetails1 in locationDetailsService.
locationDetailsService.save(locationDetails1);

You should be setting locationDetails2.

Comment: still receiving same error.

Comment: It is important to know which line is throwing error. You said, it fails when locationDetails1 is null but works when a non-null value is returned. If this is the case, then the program is failing in if block. Can you run the program in debug mode and let us know which line is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save a null object - locationDetails1 - to the database in the end.

```
locationDetailsService.save(locationDetails1);
```

Comment: i have corrected that . still does'nt work . the program terminates at the line where locationDetails1 receives a null. its not even entering to the if clause

Comment: It's probably because you are using method findById with an object instead of an ID of an object

Comment: ok then ill try by passing the id and check if its working .

Comment: not working even i pass it as Id

Comment: Can u put a stacktrace of an error? And what did you put as id exactly? Is it `locationDetailsService.findById(new LocationDetailsId(id));` or `locationDetailsService.findById(id);`